# I am trying to print to screen using thymleef and springboot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

this is what I tried to show on html

```
                             <div class="review">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!--end col-md-3-->
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <div class="comment">
                                            <div class="comment-title">
                                                <h4>
                                                    <td th:text="${username}"></td>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <dl class="visitor-rating">
                                                <dt>user ID</dt>
                                                <dd><td th:text="${userid}"></td></dd>
                                                <dt>user Tel.</dt>
                                                <dd><td th:text="${tel}"></dd>
                                                <dt>user email</dt>
                                                <dd><td th:text="${email}"></dd>
                                            </dl>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and this is how tried to send data from controller

```
    String username = memDto.getUsername();
    String email = memDto.getEmail();
    String tel = memDto.getTel1();
    String userid = memDto.getUserid();
    
    mav.addObject("username", username);
    mav.addObject("email", email);
    mav.addObject("tel", tel);
    mav.addObject("userid", userid);
```

I have data in DB and I don't know why data doesn't show up

Comment: Can you please show me your whole controller method? And what would you get in response null or any exception?

Comment: I found out I have serveral problems with my controller and I am working on it. I will reply back as soon as I fix other problems